# c++ is not a class template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I need to define a structure that has a tuple composed of a template class.

Usage:

```
TestStruct<A, float, float, int32_t> test_a = { std::make_tuple(A(1.0), A(2.0), A(3)) };
TestStruct<B, float, float, int32_t> test_b = { std::make_tuple(B(1.0), B(2.0), B(3)) };
```

At the moment my implementation looks like:

```
template<typename ClassBase, typename... ParamType>
struct TestStruct
{
    std::tuple<typename ClassBase<ParamType>...>  m_testValues;
};
```

By compiling I get following errors:

```
error: ‘ClassBase’ is not a class template
     std::tuple<class ClassBase<ParamType>...>  m_testValues;
                      ^
```

How do I have to define my structure?

Comment: What is `ParamBase` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is `A`? What is `B` ?

Comment: I suggest you focus on producing a [mcve] ahead of posting.

Comment: `A` and `B` are two different classes. The point here is how has to be declared the template structure which uses tuple. There is a syntax error that I cannot identify.

Comment: `A` and `B` are classes or templates?

Comment: Template classes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A template is not a type. This parameter `typename ClassBase` means the template must accept a type as the first parameter. But it then proceeds to treat it as a template `ClassBase<ParamType>`, which it simply isn't.

If you want a template template parameter, declare it as such:

```
template<template<class> class ClassBase, typename... ParamType>
struct TestStruct
{
    std::tuple<ClassBase<ParamType>...>  m_testValues;
};
```

Comment: In addition, usage should be modified to replace `A(1.0)` by `A<float>(1.0)`.